# return base64 image from sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to serve a tracking image in an email.

The email will call a sinatra route which will return the image.

In rails, I would do this:

```
send_data Base64.decode64("R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="), type: "image/gif", disposition: "inline"
```

How would I do this in sinatra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
get '/route' do
  content_type 'image/gif'
  Base64.decode64("R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==")
end
```

If you want to set the disposition, you can do it like this (for example):

```
headers 'Content-Disposition' => 'inline;filename="tracking.gif"'
```

or

```
attachment 'tracking.gif', 'inline'
```

Comment: What is meant with "disposition" in this context?